# How to replace GET path variable from CSV file in JMeter?

Tags: csv, jmeter, beanshell

I'm trying to replace a variable in the `GET` path without using any parameter name/value combination as the REST API is using `ODATA` format.

Example: http://localhost/GetEmployeeData('EMP12345')

In my JMeter script, I have added HTTP Request and set the path like this:

```
/GetEmployeeData('${empid}')
```

In my CSV file, I have a single column defined like this:

```
empid
EMP12345
```

In CSV Dataset config, I'm pointing to the CSV file and setting the variable name to `empid`.

What I'm doing wrong?. I get a bad request error and the `${empid}` is not getting replaced from the CSV file.

Please help.

Comment: Anybody please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot help without seeing your configuration so for the time being I can give you only few pieces of advice:

1. Check [*jmeter.log*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) file for any suspicious entries, in the absolute majority of cases you should be able to figure out the failure reason from it
2. Use full path to the CSV file instead of relative. If it helps - check out where JMeter is looking for the file by the relative path and move it into that folder.
3. Try replacing the CSV Data Set Config with [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) or [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) functions, the syntax would be:

   - `/GetEmployeeData('${__StringFromFile(/path/to/file.csv,,,)}')`
   - `/GetEmployeeData('${__CSVRead(/path/to/file.csv,0)}')`

   Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept.

---

I cannot reproduce your issue having .csv file in JMeter's "bin" folder and the following CSV Data Set Config setup:

[image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config]

[image: JMeter Variable substitution]

Comment: Awesome @Dmitri T. I set the parameter "Ignore first line..." setting to true and it worked!!. Is it always recommended to use functions than using the UI components? Also wanted to ask you is there a best online tutorial of Jmeter 4.0 from beginner to expert? I tried googling and not able to find anything.

Comment: The functions read the whole file into memory, if the file is relatively small and it is more convenient to use the functions - go for them. For larger files it is better to stick to CSV Data Set Config. With regards to tutorial - the best one is official [JMeter User Manual](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html), however you might find [JMeter Academy](https://www.blazemeter.com/jmeter-tutorial) very useful for quick ramping up on JMeter

Comment: Thanks again. I have one more issue. It only runs with the first row in the CSV file. I have a single column with 2 rows and it always picks the first row and stops. What I'm missing here?

Comment: @Appium_ios_android you should try using "Ultimate Thread Group" plugin (https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/). For me this worked like a charm.